# jQuery attribute check

Tags: jquery, if-statement, attributes

I want to make in if...else statement in jQuery but I am not sure how to set it up for what I want.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#quotes").hide();
  $("button").click(function(){
    if($("#quotes").hide()==true){
      $("#summary").hide();
      $("#quotes").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
      $("#quotes").hide();
      $("#summary").fadeIn("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

I want it so that if #quotes is hidden, then on button click, hide #summary and fadeIn #quotes. Otherwise, (if #quotes is showing) hide #quotes and fadeIn #summary.

Comment: use `$('#quotes').toggle()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    if(!$("#quotes").is(":visible")) {
        $("#summary").hide();
        $("#quotes").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        $("#quotes").hide();
        $("#summary").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: What does the ! do in if(!$("#quotes")

Comment: @TheWalkingPacifist, it negates the return value of `is()`. Therefore, the conditional expression will be `true` if the element is hidden and `false` if it is visible. You could also use the `:hidden` selector and remove the `!`, as Sudip Pal does in his answer.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and explanation is much appreciated and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the if checking like this,

```
 if($("#quotes").is(':hidden')==true){
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code

```
 $("#quotes").hide();
 $("button").click(function(){
    $("#summary").slideToggle();
    $("#quotes").slideToggle();
 });
```

Comment: Why downvote? What is the reason of making condition if there is function in jquery doing exactly this.

Comment: I did not downvote, but two calls to `slideToggle()` are not the same as one call to `show()`/`hide()` followed by one call to `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` with a `slow` duration. This code also assumes the two elements are in the appropriate initial conditions (`#summary` visible and `#quotes` hidden).